# JAVA 8 Optional map or else

Tags: java, dictionary, stream, option-type

Hello I've written statement with `Optional<Parameter>` and i return *true* if **Parameter** is present and it's value is *false*.

```
public boolean getNoDailyAllowance(String code) {
    Optional<Parameter> myParam = parameterDao.getCachedParameter(code);
    return myParam.isPresent() && !myParam.get().currentValueBoolean();
}
```

I want to rewrite it something like this

```
return calcDailyAllowanceParam.map(parameter -> Boolean.parseBoolean(parameter.getCurrentValue())).orElse(false);
```

but i can't add **!** operator before `parameter.getCurrentValue()` what i do incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution:

```java
    public boolean getNoDailyAllowance(final String code) {
        return !parameterDao
          .getCachedParameter(code)
          .map(Parameter::currentValueBoolean)
          .orElse(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `parameter.getCurrentValue()` returns `String` you cannot negate it using `!`.

You should use `!` before boolean value only:

`parameter -> ! Boolean.parseBoolean(parameter.getCurrentValue())`